# Manually adding rows in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm coding for my project that need to using node and connector on WPF. 
My node and connector class are

```
public class Node
{
    private string _nodeId;
    private string _nodeType;
    private double _x;
    private double _y;
    /*
    set/get function here
    */
}


public class Connector
{
    private string _startNodeId;
    private string _endNodeId;
    /*
    set/get function here
    */
}
```

And I want to use a datagrid to list all connectors as follows

```
-----------------------------------------
|       |   01  |   02  |   03  |   04  |
-----------------------------------------
|   01  |   x   |   1   |   0   |   1   |
-----------------------------------------
|   02  |   0   |   x   |   0   |   1   |
-----------------------------------------
|   03  |   1   |   1   |   x   |   1   |
-----------------------------------------
|   04  |   1   |   1   |   0   |   x   |
-----------------------------------------
```

On datagrid, columns and rows header are node ID in nodes list. So that I need to manually add rows to datagrid. I have searched a lot, but have no luck.

Can anyone help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create the `data source` of the data grid as a data table and then assign the source in code behind. Please see the code below.

```
    // Create a datatable for your datagrid's source
    DataTable datatbl = new DataTable();
    datatbl.Columns.Add("startNode_ID", typeof(int));
    datatbl.Columns.Add("endNode_ID", typeof(int));

    // You can add new rows to datatable here
    for (int iCount = 1; iCount < MaximumRequiredCount; iCount++)
    {
        var row = datatbl.NewRow();
        row["startNode_ID"] = Your Start Node ID;
        row["endNode_ID"] = Your End Node ID;
        datatbl.Rows.AddRow(row);
    }

    DataGridView dataGrid1 = new DataGridView();
    dataGrid1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGrid1.DataSource = datatbl;
```

Set the binding in xaml as such

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Comment: DataSource of Datagrid not avaiable in WPF. We can only use DataSource in windowForm app.

Comment: Try setting the `DataContext` or consider using a datagridview.

Comment: But, this is only small function on my project. Other tasks almost done. I can not change to using window form to use datagridview. Okie, I will try setting DataContext.

Comment: Oops.. I am sorry. Since I am working in windows forms/wpf at the moment, got confused. Yea. In WPF you can go with datagrid itself.